# Can not mock the private method with mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, powermockito

I am trying to mock a private method with power mockito, after reading this post I got some idea and I followed the same structure:

[example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28121177/mock-private-method-using-powermockito)

here is my class:

```
public class test(){
  private long verifyMarketEligibilityAndGetOfferDeliveryCalendar(long id)
  {
    some lins of code for connectiong to db
  }
  public long createOffer(long id){

    return verifyMarketEligibilityAndGetOfferDeliveryCalendar(id);
  }

}
```

And here is my mock test:

```
test classUnderTest = PowerMockito.spy(new test());
        PowerMockito.doReturn(10).when(classUnderTest,
                "verifyMarketEligibilityAndGetOfferDeliveryCalendar", 10l);
        classUnderTest.createOffer(10);
```

Now I expect that after calling createoffer, verifyMarketEligibilityAndGetOfferDeliveryCalendar does not invoke and instead number 10 returns but for some reason program start executing the verifyMarketEligibilityAndGetOfferDeliveryCalendar class and consequently db related code .

Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you have a `@PrepareForTest` on your test class.?

Comment: OOOPPPPS yep what a silly mistake, I wish you have added as an answer then i could accept it

Comment: You need some points more than me, add your "I figured it out" answer and accept it :o

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PowerMockito needs those annotations to be declared.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(classUnderTest.class)
```