# org.powermock.reflect.exceptions.MethodNotFoundException: No method found with name '' with parameter types: [ java.util.LinkedList ]

Tags: java, junit, powermock, powermockito

I am developing `Test` classes using **PowerMock**, as all my `Legacy` code is written using **Private Static** methods().

When running the test class, I am getting below error:

```
org.powermock.reflect.exceptions.MethodNotFoundException: No method found with name 'insertPaytmBilling' with parameter types: [ java.util.LinkedList ] in class com.xyz.PaytmBilling.
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.throwExceptionIfMethodWasNotFound(WhiteboxImpl.java:1122)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.findMethodOrThrowException(WhiteboxImpl.java:913)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.doInvokeMethod(WhiteboxImpl.java:807)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.invokeMethod(WhiteboxImpl.java:675)
    at org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox.invokeMethod(Whitebox.java:401)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.expectation.PowerMockitoStubberImpl.when(PowerMockitoStubberImpl.java:94)
    at safe.billing.MemberBillingTest.testMemberBilling(MemberBillingTest.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:68)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:326)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:89)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:97)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:310)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:131)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.access$100(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:59)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner$TestExecutorStatement.evaluate(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:147)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.evaluateStatement(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:107)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:298)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:87)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:50)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:218)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:160)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:134)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:136)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:121)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:57)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
```

**Method:**

```
private static void insertpaytmBilling(ArrayList allPaytmBill) throws Exception{

    Connection conn = getConnection(userId, passwd, url);

    PreparedStatement pStatement =  conn.prepareStatement(DATA_SQL);

    for (int i=0; i<allPaytmBill.size(); i++){
        MemberBill mBill = (MemberBill) allPaytmBill.get(i);

        pStatement.setString(1, mBill.getMemberId());
        ......
        ......
        ..........

        pStatement.execute();
        //pStatement.addBatch();            
    }   
    pStatement.close();
    conn.close();
}
```

**Test class:**

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ DriverManager.class, ABCHandler.class })
@PowerMockIgnore("javax.management.*")
public class PaytmBillingTest {
    @Mock
    private static Connection conn;
    List<paytmBill> paytmBillings = null;

    @Before
    public void beforeTest() {
        paytmBillings = new ArrayList<>();

        paytmBill m = new paytmBill();
        ....
        ....
        paytmBillings.add(m);
    }

    @Test
    public void testpaytmBilling() throws Exception {
        // Setup
        Connection conn = PowerMockito.mock(Connection.class);
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(DriverManager.class);
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(ABCHandler.class);
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(PreparedStatement.class);

        // Create Spy
        paytmBilling spy = PowerMockito.spy(new paytmBilling());

        BDDMockito.given(ABCHandler.getConnection(anyString(), anyString(), anyString())).willReturn(conn);

        PowerMockito.doReturn(true).when(spy, "insertpaytmBilling", anyList());

    }
}
```

**Edit-1:**

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
3 matchers expected, 1 recorded:
-> at safe.billing.MemberBillingTest.testMemberBilling(MemberBillingTest.java:76)

This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
    //incorrect:
    someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
For example:
    //correct:
    someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `paytmBilling` class in `PrepareForTest` annotation to spy on:

```
@PrepareForTest({ DriverManager.class, ABCHandler.class , paytmBilling.class)
```

Comment: @Sayali Please show `insertPaytmBilling` method signature

Comment: Why its saying not getting LinkedList with the method parameters? As I am using only ArrayList in actual method signature.

Comment: @Sayali you can be more specific, replace `anyList()` with `any(ArrayList.class)`

Comment: @Sayali this is different issue and I think different line.

Comment: - Any thoughts how to fixed this ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues. First with the parameter type. The fix was suggested in the comments:

> be more specific, replace anyList() with any(ArrayList.class)

When you use a construction like:

```
PowerMockito.doReturn(true).when(spy, "insertpaytmBilling", anyList())
```

PowerMock is looking for a method with the name "insertpaytmBilling" in spy's class with a list of parameters assignable to the given list of parameters. Looks like the issue in your case that `anyList()` by default returns an instance of `LinkedList` which is not assignable to a real parameter of the method `ArrayList`.

The second issue (Edit-1) is that Mockito does not support and cannot support mocking with using matches and raw parameters together. You should always use either matcher like `anyString()` or parameter `Some string`. As I see from the code snippet and stack trace the exception is thrown in another part of the test.